# Node zlib module inflate, and knowing how much data was read (total_in)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib, node-modules

I'm trying to parse out a stream of data which contains sequences of Zlib compressed data. To do this, I need to know how much data is read for decompressing, so I know where to continue reading from for the next decompression.

[In the native zlib library](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html), this value would be exposed through the `total_in` member of the `z_stream_s` struct.

I can do this with the JavaScript port of zlib [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako), but I would prefer to use [the native Node module](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html), as it would avoid the extra dependency and has asyncronous support.

Here's a code sample that shows this dilemma in action.

```
'use strict';

const zlib = require('zlib');
const pako = require('pako');

const str = 'testing';
const extra = new Uint8Array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);

const data = new Uint8Array(zlib.deflateSync(str));

const dataExtra = new Uint8Array(data.length + extra.length);
dataExtra.set(data);
dataExtra.set(extra, data.length);

console.log(data);
console.log(dataExtra);


// Inflate with pako module.
// Accessing the amount read is easy.
const pakoInflate = new pako.Inflate();
pakoInflate.push(dataExtra, true);
const pakoInflated = new Buffer(pakoInflate.result.buffer);
console.log(pakoInflated, pakoInflated.toString());
console.log(pakoInflate.strm.total_in);


// Inflate with zlib module.
// Any way to know how much data was actually read?
const zlibInflated = zlib.inflateSync(new Buffer(dataExtra));
console.log(zlibInflated, zlibInflated.toString());
```

Sample output (the 15 being the length of the compressed data read):

```
Uint8Array [ 120, 156, 43, 73, 45, 46, 201, 204, 75, 7, 0, 12, 30, 2, 255 ]
Uint8Array [ 120, 156, 43, 73, 45, 46, 201, 204, 75, 7, 0, 12, 30, 2, 255, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
<Buffer 74 65 73 74 69 6e 67> 'testing'
15
<Buffer 74 65 73 74 69 6e 67> 'testing'
```

It appears that `zlib.inflate*` methods do not expose this information, but is there another way to do this? Perhaps one of the other methods of the `zlib` module enables this? Or is this information completely unavailable to JavaScript code?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's being exposed in any way.

Comment: It is a deficiency in the interface. You should request something like python's `unused_data`, which is the correct way to remedy this. `total_in` is not the way to do it, since that counter could in principle overflow for large input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node didn't expose this feature before, so I submitted some pull requests to add it.

As of Node 8.1 this is now possible to access this information with the native `zlib` module. The Zlib engines now make a [`bytesRead`](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_bytesread) property available, and the convenience methods can now access it by passing [an `info` option](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_options).

### Working Example:

```
'use strict';

const zlib = require('zlib');

const str = 'abcdefgh'.repeat(2);
const data = new Uint8Array(zlib.deflateSync(str));
const extra = new Uint8Array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);

const dataExtra = new Uint8Array(data.length + extra.length);
dataExtra.set(data);
dataExtra.set(extra, data.length);

testSync();

function testSync() {
    const info = zlib.inflateSync(dataExtra, {info: true});
    console.log('Sync:');
    console.log(str, '==', info.buffer.toString());
    console.log(data.length, '==', info.engine.bytesRead);
    console.log();

    testAsync();
}

function testAsync() {
    zlib.inflate(dataExtra, {info: true}, (err, info) => {
        console.log('Async:');
        console.log(str, '==', info.buffer.toString());
        console.log(data.length, '==', info.engine.bytesRead);
        console.log();

        testStream();
    });
}

function testStream() {
    let buffer = new Buffer(0);

    const inf = new zlib.Inflate();
    inf.on('data', (d) => {
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, d]);
    });
    inf.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Stream:');
        console.log(str, '==', buffer.toString());
        console.log(data.length, '==', inf.bytesRead);
        console.log();
    });
    inf.write(dataExtra);
    inf.end();
}
```

---

It's also technically possible to do this with older Node versions, though it requires some monkey-patching of the private properties. You also have to use the stream object directly.

### Monkey-patch Example (for old Node versions):

```
'use strict';

const zlib = require('zlib');

const str = 'abcdefgh'.repeat(2);
const data = new Uint8Array(zlib.deflateSync(str));
const extra = new Uint8Array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);

const dataExtra = new Uint8Array(data.length + extra.length);
dataExtra.set(data);
dataExtra.set(extra, data.length);

class Inflate extends zlib.Inflate {
    constructor(opts, mode) {
        super(opts, mode);

        if (!('bytesRead' in this)) {
            const self = this;
            this.bytesRead = 0;

            const handle = this._handle;
            const writeSync = handle.writeSync;
            handle.writeSync = function() {
                const availInBefore = arguments[3];
                const r = writeSync.apply(this, arguments);
                self.bytesRead += availInBefore - r[0];
                return r;
            };
            const write = handle.write;
            handle.write = function() {
                const availInBefore = arguments[3];
                const r = write.apply(this, arguments);
                let callback;
                const cb = function() {
                    self.bytesRead += availInBefore - arguments[0];
                    callback.apply(r, arguments);
                };
                Object.defineProperty(r, 'callback', {
                    configurable: true,
                    enumerable: true,
                    get: () => {
                        return cb;
                    },
                    set: (value) => {
                        callback = value;
                    }
                });
                return r;
            };
        }
    }
}

testSync();

function testSync() {
    const inf = new Inflate();
    const buffer = inf._processChunk(dataExtra, inf._finishFlushFlag);
    inf.end();
    console.log('Sync:');
    console.log(str, '==', buffer.toString());
    console.log(data.length, '==', inf.bytesRead);
    console.log();

    testAsync();
}

function testAsync() {
    let buffer = new Buffer(0);
    const inf = new Inflate();
    inf.on('data', (d) => {
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, d]);
    });
    inf.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Async:');
        console.log(str, '==', buffer.toString());
        console.log(data.length, '==', inf.bytesRead);
        console.log();
    });
    inf.write(dataExtra);
    inf.end();
}
```